# Why is the Microsoft Management Console empty on my EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, mmc

This is a brand new Windows Server 2022 EC2 instance. I am Administrator.

I'm trying to use NICE DCV. I have it installed, I guess, but I don't see it anywhere. [Amazon's instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dcv/latest/adminguide/manage-start.html) are to start it from the MMC but the MMC is empty.

[image]

To open MMC I do win+r>mmc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MMC is always empty until you choose Snap-ins. Go to "File > Add/Remove Snap-in". Then "Add" those you want to use and follow the prompts. In your case, it is the "Services" snap-in.

Another way to open it directly is to use "Win+R" > type "services.msc" > hit Enter. It also opens the list of services.